# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: support

Why was this answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/51696/40252 to this question [Is "Stranded in the middle of the room" by retired NASA astronaut Dan Barry the unvarnished truth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51610/is-stranded-in-the-middle-of-the-room-by-retired-nasa-astronaut-dan-barry-the?noredirect=1#comment171263_51610) deleted by https://space.stackexchange.com/users/58/called2voyage who is a moderator named called2voyage here, a few hours ago?

Comment: Your links here are invalid.  I can't tell which answer (or user) you are talking about.

Comment: You have to add links in the body of the question, not the title. Try adding the links to the body of your question.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto It worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

You were using the answer space to continue the opinion piece that you started in the question. That's not what this site is for. The question was correctly closed as being too opinion based. It cannot be answered within the constraints of this site until the issues brought up in the comments are addressed. I was responding to a flag on the answer that correctly marked it as "not an answer" within the site guidelines.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'opinion based'. Whether it happened is a matter of fact, not opinion. There were, besides Barry, at least two 'friends' who placed him at the 'middle of the room'.

Comment: Examples of opinion-wording in the question include: "unvarnished", "I don't think it really happened", the whole section titled "My reasoning is as follows" (which basically argues why you don't think it's true instead of keeping the tone of the question neutral), and "On the other hand, I guess anyone who believes/believed that the story really happened is likely to feel embarrassed about that".

Comment: I understand the desire to make clear why you feel the need to question the source, but there are less leading ways to express that, for example: "I read this anecdote in a book by an astronaut, and this section reads a bit jocular to me. Some seem to take it at face value, however. Does anyone know if there are other accounts that record this incident or a similar incident?"

Comment: If I edit the question to make it like what you are indicating would be preferable, do you think it will be reopened?

Comment: Possibly. I wasn't the only close voter, so I can't speak for everyone. I wouldn't be comfortable unilaterally reopening it with that being the case.

Comment: Is there anything else wrong with the question?

Comment: Some of the other users picked other close reasons so they might think so. Off the top of my head, I don't have any guesses what, nor do I think guessing would be helpful anyway.